is there an 'or' feature with powershell wildcards?
I am trying to figure out if it possible to match mkv or mp4 with get-childItem. Looking at the about_wildcards page there does not seem to be specific mentions of "or". I tried anyways:
get-ChildItem -path 'c:/temp' -File -Filter '[*mkv][*mp4]'
get-ChildItem -path 'c:/temp' -File -Filter '[*mkv][*mp4]?'
get-ChildItem -path 'c:/temp' -File -Filter '[*mkv]?[*mp4]?'

the "temp" directory has mp4 and mkv files in it, so I am expecting the above to return them...but I get nothing.
I know this is a trivial matter with something like -match or where-object but I am looking to take advantage of wildcards as it would mean I can do everything in one call.
Am looking so know if such a is even possible with pwsh wildcards. I am on pwsh 7.4

AFAIK you cannot use filter with multiple arguments. It is a limitation of the file system provider used. You would need to use -Include or implement a Where in the pipe. And about the wildcard, the documentation says the -Filter parameter only handles the ? and * characters. (ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.4)

You could say -path c:\temp\*.mkv,c:\temp\*.mp4

The best single wildcard pattern you can use is probably *.m[kp][v4] but you must use -Include if you want that pattern to work, and even then it will fail in some cases, i.e.:
$wildcard = '*.m[kp][v4]'
'foo.mp4' -like $wildcard # True, OK
'foo.mkv' -like $wildcard # True, OK
'foo.mpv' -like $wildcard # True, Wrong
'foo.mk4' -like $wildcard # True, Wrong
'foo.mXX' -like $wildcard # False, OK

-Include uses WildcardPattern for matching (same as -like in above example), this class offers a wider range of wildcard characters than -Filter which only supports ? and *. The parameter also takes an array of patterns, so you can simply do:
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\* -File -Include *.mp4, *.mkv


-Include supports an array of filters: -Include *.mkv, *.mp4

oh i totally forgot about that lol! i guess i never use that parameter xd, thanks @zett42
